# Site scope - are questions asking about how to test and/or alter your specific design to be better testable on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm primarily active on Code Review, where we review people's code. Someone posted a question there that was about improving the testability of their code.

You'll need 10k rep to see it, so here's a link and an image:

[How to effectively test DAO classes using spring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134946/how-to-effectively-test-dao-classes-using-spring)

[image]

I understand that if you look at this question, it's more a code review request than would be appropriate here, but if you alter the wording to suit the main question (how do I effectively test DAO classes in Spring) then it seems like it could fit here?

Since the asker has deleted their question, this is less about this specific question and more about "do you take such implementation-specific questions". I'd like to know for next time that such a thing happens, so that I can point users here, rather than just state "sorry, your question is off-topic at Code Review, kthxbye".

I had a look at your tour too; it's not very specific as it just states that "Specific issues with software quality assurance or testing" are on topic and "Anything not directly related to software quality assurance or testing" is off topic, and this seems more than just tangentially related.

---

Additional request: you guys need a [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope) tag. Would you mind making it?

Comment: What is the purpose of a site-scope tag?

Comment: @user246 it's for browsing questions that talk about whether things are on or off-topic. It's about site-boundaries. Mainly the purpose is for refining searches.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for thinking of us!

I would say this falls under the scope of the site as far as it pertains to the implementation. The site actually had Selenium merged into it, so ALL things Selenium are clearly on topic. I don't see why JUnit would be any different. Now, things that are actually Java questions that merely happen to be used in a testing tool like Selenium or JUnit those are less likely to be on topic. Based on the image you linked, I believe it is a candidate for migration here in the future.

However, I'm only one voice, and leave the floor open to alternative views.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am not seasoned on this site yet...